# Assertion Failure in UITableView - Cant locate the problematic part

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, delete-row

I have a tableviewcontroller and a fetchresultscontroller which fills the table with objects values. I am trying then to delete an object from the core data model as well as the row from the table through commitEditingStyle, but I get this error. I am aware of the error meaning, but I can't figure out what I need to fix in my code to make it disappear. Any help is appreciated.

**Error:**

```
EcoShoppingUI[1365:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1368
2014-07-25 15:03:42.137 EcoShoppingUI[1365:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

**favTable.m**

```
#import "favTable.h"
#import "ecoAppDelegate.h"
#import "favCell.h"
#import "favButton.h"
#import "FavoritesInfo.h"





@interface favTable ()


@end

@implementation favTable

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController;




- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!fetchedResultsController) {

        self.managedObjectContext = ((ecoAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;


        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                       entityForName:@"FavoritesInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];



        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];


        NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                            managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                       cacheName:@"Root"];
        fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    }


    return fetchedResultsController;

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Favorites";


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;


    self.managedObjectContext = ((ecoAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;


    NSError *error;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{


    [self setTableView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    id  sectionInfo =
    [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];




//   NSLog(@"%zd", [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]); // amount of fetched objects

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

}





- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"favCell";


    favCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[favCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

   [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.cellmanu.text = @"hhjh";

    cell.cellimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.jpg"];



    return cell;
}


- (void)configureCell:(favCell *)cell
          atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    FavoritesInfo*favoritesInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.cellname.text = favoritesInfo.name;
    cell.cellscore.text = favoritesInfo.score;

    }




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        ecoAppDelegate *appDelegatee = (ecoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


        self.managedObjectContext = ((ecoAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;


        FavoritesInfo*favoritesInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [tableView
         deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:favoritesInfo];


        [appDelegatee saveContext]; // to save changes

        NSError *error= nil;

        if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            exit(-1);  // Fail
        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}




// FetchedResultsController update methods



- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to delete the object from managedObjectContext then save the context. The fetch results controller delegate will take care of updating the table view. Remove the [tableView deleteRows... line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        ecoAppDelegate *appDelegatee = (ecoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        FavoritesInfo*favoritesInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:favoritesInfo];


        [appDelegatee saveContext]; // to save changes

    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

It's hard to know what some bits of your code are doing, seeing as you are referencing your app delegate. Let me know what this does. it **should** sort the issue but i'm not 100%.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However it didn't fix the issue

Comment: It's still crashing ?

Comment: What do you do in appDelegatee saveContext ?

Answer (score 0):

Your section header column should be the first attribute in sort order.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by section header column. Can you please explain?